# Pepper NAOqi 2.5: How to create a callback function from an event?

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

I'm working on Pepper from SoftBank Robotics and I'm trying to realize a program that is able to integrate a callback function once a "Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/ObstacleDetected" event goes TRUE.

Of course, I tried to refer the manual but in the [Reacting to Events](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/other-tutorials/python-sdk-tutorials/reacting-events) section of the Python SDK there is only an example that uses the FaceDetect event.

Unfortunately, differently from FaceDetect event, which is part of the ALFaceDetection service that has a subscribe method, "Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/ObstacleDetected" event is associated with ALNavigation API that doesn't have the subscriber.

Someone can help me with this?

Here my first (not working) idea:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-


from naoqi import ALProxy
import qi
import argparse
import sys
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import os
import time


class tryGetEvent(object):


    def __init__(self, app):
        super(tryGetEvent, self).__init__()
        app.start()                 #start the application (see qi.ApplicationAPI)
        session=app.session         #return the current session

        # Open the service ALMemory

        self.memory=session.service("ALMemory")

        #Connect to the event callback
        self.subscriber=self.memory.subscriber("Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/ObstacleDetected")
        self.subscriber.signal.connect(self.obstacleDet)

        self.tts=session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
        self.navigation=session.service("ALNavigation")
        self.navigation.subscribe("tryGetEvent")
        self.got_obst=False

    def obstacleDet(self, position):

        if position==[]: #empty value
            self.got_obst=False
        elif not self.got_obst:
            self.got_obst=True
            print "Obstacle detected!"
            self.tts.say("Obstacle detected!")

            pos_plot=position [1]

            print (pos_plot)

    def run(self):

        print("Starting script tryGetEvent")
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.2)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("user interrupted the script")
            self.navigation.unsubscribe("tryGetEvent")
            sys.exit(0)



# DO NOT TOUCH !

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", type=str, default="192.168.1.32",
                        help="Robot IP address. On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=9559,
                        help="Naoqi port number")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        # Initialize qi framework.
        connection_url = "tcp://" + args.ip + ":" + str(args.port)
        app = qi.Application(["tryGetEvent", "--qi-url=" + connection_url])
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + args.ip + "\" on port " + str(args.port) +".\n"
               "Please check your script arguments. Run with -h option for help.")
        sys.exit(1)


    Get_Event=tryGetEvent(app)
    Get_Event.run()
```

Comment: ALNavigation doesn't have a subscribe method. Try starting ALNavigation by using [navigateTo](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-motion/alnavigation/alnavigation-api#ALNavigationProxy::navigateTo__floatCR.floatCR) for example. That should activate the ALNavigation, make Pepper start moving, and detect obstacles.

Comment: @DominicD I got your point, but I need to manage a callback function concerning the navigation in Python SDK. But the only example they provide for callback functions is by using subscribe. So, the real problem is that I still don't know how to mange it.

Comment: I think your code for setting up the callback is fine (I can't test at the moment unfortunately). Try and remove `self.navigation.subscribe("tryGetEvent")` from your `__init__()` and add `self.navigation.navigateTo(5.0, 0.0)` to the start of `run()`. That'll make Pepper start navigating, which should make the event occur (and trigger your callback).

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to see that the manual's example is unclear, but there is a simpler way to write this code.

`obstacle_tracker.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-
import qi

class ObstacleTracker:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session
        self.got_obst = False
        memory = session.service("ALMemory")
        subscriber = memory.subscriber("Navigation/AvoidanceNavigator/ObstacleDetected")
        subscriber.signal.connect(self.obstacleDet)

    def obstacleDet(self, position):
        if position == []: #empty value
            self.got_obst = False
        elif not self.got_obst:
            self.got_obst = True
            print("Obstacle detected!")
            tts = self.session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
            tts.say("Obstacle detected!")
            print(position)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qi.Application()
    app.start()
    obstacle_tracker = ObstacleTracker(app.session)
    app.run()
```

Run it with:
`$ python obstacle_tracker.py --qi-url=192.168.1.32`